# python ftp retrieve lines -- performance issues

Tags: python, performance, ftp

I am trying to retrieve lines from a file through a FTP connection using the `ftplib` module of python. It takes about 10 mins to read a file of size 1 GB. I was wondering if there are any other ways to read the lines in a faster manner.

I should have included some code to show what I am doing:

```
ftp.HostName = 'xxx'
ftp.Userid = 'xxx' #so on

ftp.conn.retrlines('RETR ' + fileName, process)
```

Comment: No.  What makes you think it's your Python app that's slow?  Have you tried other FTP clients and measured the time they take?

Answer (score 1):

Retrieving remote resources is usually bound by your bandwidth, and FTP protocol does a decent job of using it all.

Are you sure you aren't saturating your network connection?  (what is the network link between client running ftplib and server you are downloading from?)

Back of the envelope calc:

1GB/10mins =~ 1.7 MB/sec =~ 13 Mbps

So you are downloading at 13 megabit.  That's decent speed for a remote DSL/Cable/WAN connection, but obviously pretty low if this is all a local network.

Comment: +1 for a good answer.  I suggest you use proper capitalization as that is the general practice in Stack Overflow.

Comment: fixed caps.. too used to irc :)

Comment: so `.retrlines('RETR ' + fileName, callback)` is the fastest way to retrieve lines then?

Answer (score 0):

Can you show some minimal code sample of what you are doing? FTP is for transporting files,
so retrieving lines from a remote file isn't necessarily as efficient as transferring the file in whole once and reading it locally.

Aside from that, have you verified, that you *can* be faster on this connection?

EDIT: if you try the following and it is not a bit faster, then you are limited by your OS or your connection:

```
ftp.conn.retrbinary('RETR ' + fileName, open(temp_file_name, 'wb').write)
```

The assumption here is, that FTP text mode might be somewhat less efficient (on the server side), which might be false or of miniscule relevance.